# MAC detection in bluetooth

Tags: linux, kali-linux, virtual-machine, bluetooth, bluez

I have bluetooth dongle connected to my system which is having kali linux installed on VM . Now in kali linux When i run hcitool or l2ping command it detects other bluetooth devices mac addresses but my device MAC is not detecting. Whereas, when i scan using nrfConnect my device mac is visible also my device MAC is visible when i  scan using bluetoothctl command . Any specific reason my device MAC is not visible when scan using hcitool , redfang , l2ping or spooftoph.

Comment: what is "your device"? Is it the device the Kali VM runs on?

Comment: Its an external transmitter which supports BLE 5.0

Comment: Its an external peripheral device or transmitter which supports BLE 5.0 and i am trying to scan this device using bluetooth dongle connected to my system . My system have kali linux installed on VM and configured for bluetooth. I am able to scan other available bluetooth devices mac addresses using  hcitool or l2ping command. But my device MAC is not detecting. i can scan my device using nrfConnect and bluetoothctl command but not using hcitool , redfang , l2ping or spooftoph.